# Custom Button on PDF page-Visualforce

Tags: visualforce

[image]Is it possible to add custom button on PDF page,like on this image?

Comment: The area you have marked are not part of PDF, they are part of Chrome PDF viewer. So it is not possible to put any button in those areas. What is your actual requirement?

Answer (score 2):

You couldn't put any kind of "button" on a PDF page. Active content isn't supported when rendering PDFs. See [Component Behavior When Rendered as PDF](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_output_pdf_component_behavior.htm) for more on components that are "Safe", ones to "Use with Caution", and "Unsafe Components" when rendering PDFs.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Is it possible to make it somehow? It should be somewhere on page...

Comment: Igor, it absolutely cannot be in the code used to render the page. Any kind of active content, meaning something that's "clickable" or has a link to execute javascript, an Ajax Call, or action link cannot appear in the code for a page that's being rendered using the Salesforce Render Engine. It isn't that PDF's don't support them, it's that the Flying Saucer Render Engine used by Salesforce doesn't support rendering them. Your page won't "print" at render time.